# how to send data to the node js server using GET method?

Tags: jquery, node.js, methods, get, node-modules

I am using get Method and trying to send data to my `nodejs` server

using Jquery ajax call
here is my code of send data to the `node`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    usid();
function usid(med){
  console.log("I am In");
  var f = "my new name";
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url:"http://localhost:8080/listUsers",
    method:"GET",
    data:{med:med,f:f},
    success:function(data,status){
      console.log("send");
    }
  })
}
 })
```

and in my node js sever I am trying to get this data
here is my node js code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require("path");
var cons = require('consolidate'); 
var cors = require('cors');
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM("")
const params = require('params');
const jquery = require('jquery')(dom.window)
var app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "www")));
app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
res.render('try');
    var f = (req.body.f);
    console.log("hello" + f);
})
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

but in my console I am facing the Undifined error

can you tell me what am I missing here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests do not have a body (req.body). You could change the request to a POST and then you will have a body or you can use the queryString. Here is an example https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/

```
 $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url:"http://localhost:8080/listUsers?med=" + med + "&f=" + f,
    method:"GET",
    success:function(data,status){
      console.log("send");
    }
  })
```

Then on the server

```
app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
    var f = (req.query.f);
    console.log("hello" + f);
})
```

Comment: what if I want to add a variable in my URL: like  I have tried this ` // url:"http://localhost:8081/join"+roomId"?med=" + med + "&f=" + f,` but its not working Can you help in this too ?@tanner burton

Comment: that can be done with path parameters https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-path-parameters-in-node-js/ 'localhost:8081/join/:roomId?med=med1&f=f1'

Comment: `jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 GET http://localhost:3000/join/:roomId?med=undefined&f=my%20new%20name 500 (Internal Server Error)` getting this error @tanner burton